# iMacros -- Extracting Specific Text from a Site Using Javascript Site

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, imacros

I'm brand new to iMacros and know no programming, so apologies if this is a silly question. I'm using the Firefox extension of iMacros and having some difficulty extracting text from a site.

When you search for an address at http://schools.nyc.gov/schoolsearch the site uses javascript and returns some information in the left column.  I'm interested in extracting a small bit of that information -- it's a 4-digit code, such as M301, that appears under the first heading "Zoned Elementary Schools." It's always the first instance of text in between parentheses, i.e. it shows up like this: (M301)

What I want to do is extract only the 4-digit code.  But since the site uses javascript, the only thing I can see to grab in the code is the entire left pane -- by using TAG with TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:leftcolumn.  But that gives me the entire left column, which I don't want.

Can anyone explain how I might isolate the 4-digit string from the rest of the text on the left column?  For reference, this is what I have (I'm sure it's really inelegant even without doing what I want):

```
VERSION BUILD=8240212 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE File with Addresses.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=http://schools.nyc.gov/schoolsearch/
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#Autocomplete1_SchoolComboBox_Input" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#Autocomplete1_SchoolComboBox_Input" CHARS={{!COL1}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#header>DIV:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#search_label" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#doe_widget_ResultsManager_0>H3" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:leftcolumn EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=folder FILE=CSV file
```

Comment: iMacros isn't really programming so you won't get a good response here. Maybe you want to take a look at selenium.